# Youtube Videos won't play on Firefox

Tags: youtube, firefox

Some videos on Youtube refuse to play for me on Firefox - the page loads fine, but the video just has the circular loading graphic indefinitely spinning around.

These very same videos always play immediately in other web browsers. I am testing with Chrome and Edge on a Windows PC.

I have tried clearing cookies for Youtube, I have tried disabling all of my Firefox extensions & mods (I only use 3 anyway), I have tried opening the video in an incognito window.

None of this works. Firefox just refuses to play some videos on Youtube.

---

Has anyone else experienced this?

Is this a known issue with Firefox and/or Youtube?

If anyone has experienced this, are there any known fixes or work arounds?